# Selecting the visible div from a set of them using their class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, visible

I have only one visible `div` between a lot of them. How can select it?

Following code works in localhost but not online:

```
var page_div_visible = $(".gform_page").filter(":visible");
```

I know that could walk through `divs` using .each() and select with .is(":visible") but 
I would prefer one line solution. Is't possible?

**EDIT:**

html looks like this:

```
<div id='gform_page_20_6' class='gform_page' style='display:none;'>
</div>
<div id='gform_page_20_7' class='gform_page' style='display:none;'>
</div>
<div id='gform_page_20_8' class='gform_page' >
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

It was not possible make it works online. This is the **final solution**:

```
var page_div_visible;

$(".gform_page").each(function(i){
    if ($(this).css("display") !== "none"){
        page_div_visible = $(this);
        return false;
    }
})
```

Thanks for your support.-

Comment: It's the same thing but try this: `var page_div_visible = $(".gform_page:visible");`

Comment: Just a hunch, but you're probably making that selector query before new elements with that class are added dynamically with JS. Or a bunch are removed and new ones added. It's not like CSS. If an element isn't there when page_div_visible is assigned to, it won't automagically be in that object and JPack's answer should work if elements with that class are present when page_div_visible is created and if nothing changed when you do something with it.

Comment: @erik-reppen divs are clearly hidden/visble when page loads. See questions edited. thx.-

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do this?

```
 var page_div_visible = $(".gform_page:visible");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaPack/AtBx3/1/

Comment: Yes, I know but some other js code is interfering with mine (this is part of a WP plugin) I need another solution.- thx

Comment: I suppose than you will have to debug it. If you don't already do so, use firebug: http://getfirebug.com/ to see any errors, or in chrome or Firefox you can use CTRL + SHIFT + J to open the javascript error console

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? May be you are also having a conflict with $ or adding classes to divs after your code.

Looking at your comment that it is being interfered by some other js code, kindly try using jQuery instead of $

```js
// at the very beginning of your main JavaScript file
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

// at the place where you are doing other stuff with $, like your issue
var page_div_visible = jQ(".gform_page:visible");
```